# Contact Record - System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, failing-tests, queryexception

```
Task a=new Task();
a.whatid=Acc.id;
a.Status='Communication Sent';
a.Action__c='Auto Execute';
a.Adhoc_Communication__c=True;
a.Email_Address__c='henry@gamil.com';
a.Encrypted_Reference_Number__c=
insert a;
```

I am trying to insert a `Task` in my test class. The insert trigger is firing, which contains:

```
Contact CT = [Select Id,Email from contact where name = 'Do Not Delete'];
    CT.Email = strEmailId;
    update CT;
```

I was getting the error

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Answer (score 2):

Unlike with `User` data and a few other objects, you don't get to see `Contact` records in a `Test` without setting `SeeAllData=true`. Much better than using that flag, however, is to just create this data in a `@TestSetup` method. You might also wish to move the string `'Do Not Delete'` to a constant somewhere.

```
static final String DO_NOT_DELETE = 'Do Not Delete';
@TestSetup
static void setup()
{
    Contact requiredContact = new Contact(LastName=DO_NOT_DELETE);
    // set required fields;
    insert requiredContact;
}
```

See also: **[Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)**

Comment: Field is not writeable: Contact.Name

Comment: @keerthanachowdhary You just need to set `LastName` instead.